# Should I use custom function to get server side translations in next.js 13 in a production aplication instead of using next-intl Server Components

Tags: next.js, internationalization, server-side-rendering, next-intl

I want to apply internationalization in my next.js (production) app (using the app directory). next-intl is stable for client components but not for server components. However, I am considering using a custom server-side function to get translations instead of using a package in the beta version. What do you think would be a good practice?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code example -

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';

async function getServerSideMessages(locale: string, page: string) {
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', 'messages', `${locale}.json`);
    console.log('filePath', filePath);
    const json = await readFile(filePath);
    const messages = JSON.parse(json.toString());
    return messages[page];
}

export default getServerSideMessages;
```

```
export default async function Home({ params }: { params: { locale: string } }) {
    console.log('params', params.locale);
    const t = await getServerSideMessages(params.locale, 'home_page');
    return (
        <>
            <h1>{t.title}</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: next-intl 3.0.0 is on rc now, not beta. which means it's about to be released to the latest very soon